# Adding A Different Character to Gibbed Borderlands 2 Save Editor

Tags: borderlands-2

I've added a new character to my Borderlands 2 game on Steam. I'd like to play with several friends who are higher levels (30-64).How might I accomplish this without destroying my Commando (Lvl 72, UVHM)? Nothing I've tried has allowed me to save both characters.

Thanks.

PRS

Comment: I've edited multiple characters without trouble. Are you sure you're saving each character to the right save file? There should be two, just edit and save them separately and it should work fine.

Comment: Hi Ben and thanks. I have save0001.sav through save0004.sav. I've been using 0001 exclusively as I don't know what the other's are for. I'd like to open the game and see both characters and be able to use gibbed's save editor with both characters.

Comment: Open the other .savs, there's only one sav per character since the game auto-saves, your other char should be in one of them

Answer (score 1):

Using Gibbed for Borderlands 2: 
1. Create a new save file in Gibbbed
2. Edit to your liking (eg. Level, Gear, Stats, Appearance (Give it a unique character name))
3. Save into your saves folder as Save000(highest number).sav. 
For your highest number use the current save files and add one to the highest number which is displayed in the names of the saves. eg: `save0006.sav` as highest and `save0007.sav` as yours.
4. Save and choose the character with your "Unique" name.